# different id for same element visual composer

Tags: php, functions

I have two same elements in visual composer page, I wanna add different custom id to this elements.

```
<div class="posts">
    // code
</div>

<div class="posts">
    // code
</div>
```

Comment: please check url :https://visualcomposer.com/help/content-elements-structure/element-id-extra-class-name/

Comment: hi stefan solve your problem ?

Comment: Thank you for replay @vikrant-zilpe. No doesn't solved, because i don't wanna enter id, i wanna when user added a element, id added automatic to element, or writing a code for adding a number to elements if there is same element.

Comment: ok no problem i find solution for you thanks for your message